# "Мастер и Маргарита" - он заслужил покой/покоя

Tags: падежи, литература, управление, литературоведение

***Почему здесь использован родительный падеж (света) в одном случае, но винительный (покой) в другом?!*** Наличие отрицания тут ничего не объясняет, "заслужил покоя" смотрелось бы более органично.

UPD
По поводу "мнения о мнении".

> Некоторые глаголы имеют при себе управляемое слово в различных
>   предложно-падежных формах, что связано с разными смысловыми или
>   стилистическими оттенками. Сюда относятся:
>    ...
>   заслужить что (своими поступками, деятельностью добиться положительной
>   или отрицательной оценки: заслужить доверие избирателей, заслужить
>   порицание) – заслуживать чего (быть достойным чего-л.: проект
>   заслуживает внимания);

Розенталь, ЛРТ
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm

Истины ради упомяну, что по сети гуляют и иные рекомендации, в частности ссылаются на якобы некое мнение gramota.ru, что выбор падежа определяется видом глагола (винительный для совершенного, родительный для несовершенного), но на самой грамоте я такого не видел, да и сомнительно как-то.

UPD-2
В Нацкорпусе не так много примеров на "заслужил чего", но они есть. 
Из безусловно авторитетных ограничусь одним.

> ***И он сам, Юрий Юрьевич, тоже этого заслужил.*** [Сергей Залыгин. Уроки 
>   правнука Вовки // «Новый мир», 1997]

UPD-3

> ***Особой милости его святейшества заслужил он***, вырезав на плоском,
>   большом изумруде, в подражание древним камням, Венеру Каллипигу; она
>   так понравилась папе, что этот камень он велел вставить в крест,
>   которым благословлял народ во время торжественных служб в соборе
>   Петра, и таким образом, целуя Распятие, целовал прекрасную богиню. [Д.
>   С. Мережковский. Воскресшие Боги. Леонардо да Винчи (1901)]

//===========

Второй вопрос на тему света и покоя - здесь: ["Мастер и Маргарита": противопоставление света и покоя.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445028)

Comment: *"заслужил покоя" смотрелось бы более органично* – это ваше мнение, и притом весьма странное. Заслужил кого-чего?

Comment: @Niemand да это мое мнение. Вам не откажешь в сообразительности.

Comment: Надо так прямо и говорить, если это мнение явно расходится с существующими нормами. Правила, мол, знаю, но все равно имею мнение.

Comment: @Niemand Если вы не знаете правила, то задайте вопрос. Я с удовольствием вам о них расскажу. Но не в этой теме.

Answer (score 2):

Частичный ответ по вопросу управления. В справочнике Д.Э. Розенталя по поводу глаголов **заслужить, заслуживать** всё категорично и вполне соответствует правилу (из другой книги Розенталя), приведенному в вопросе:

> ЗАСЛУЖИВАТЬ чего (**не что!**). Сообщение заслуживает доверия; Проект
>   заслуживает одобрения.
>   ЗАСЛУЖИТЬ что (**не чего!**). Заслужить награду;
>   Они вполне заслужили свое положение и счастье (Кав.).

Не совсем понятно, как на основании этого правила можно сделать вывод, что "заслужил **покоя** смотрится более органично".

Comment: Какой справочник - и почему вы считаете эту категоричность более категоричной чем управление в зависимости от смысла? Я-то не на это  "правило" ссылаюсь а на  "заслуживать чего - быть достойным чего-л". Тут у Булгакова явно такой смысл. Мастер заслуживает некой награды (каковую еще не получил, кстати).

Comment: @behemothus Розенталь Д.Э. Словарь-справочник "Управление в русском языке", 1997 г.

Comment: ОК, спасибо. Найду - посмотрю.  За это вам пример из Мережковского, который Розенталя тоже не читал. (В тексте вопроса).

Answer (score 2):

Я попробую ответить, но без ссылок на справочники (это чисто субъективное мнение).

*Он не заслужил света, он заслужил покой*.

Возможно, здесь просто соблюдены формальные правила, но не исключено, что выбор падежа имеет определенный смысл.

Свет и покой – понятия разные. Свет (в его особом понимании) бесконечен, его нельзя заслужить и получить в свое полное распоряжение, а именно таково значение В.п. (действие полностью охватывает предмет). Поэтому можно сказать: *он заслужил света, он не заслужил света.*

Родительный падеж обозначает часть предмета, границы предмета, но не весь предмет.

Это значение и  в приведенном примере: *Он заслужил милости* (но не всю милость) его святейшества.

Покой – это состояние, которое может получить каждый в свое полное распоряжение, поэтому *он заслужил покой*.

Comment: Мне нравится ваш подход. Но тут, на ресурсе, подобные вещи действительно требуют какого-то подтверждения ссылками. А второе. А как вы вообще понимаете "свет" и "покой"? Вопрос о падеже в общем-то частный, тут смысл самого высказывания неочевиден.

Comment: О ПРАВИЛАХ И ССЫЛКАХ. Русское правописание  основано преимущественно на грамматике, это относится и к  правилам выбора падежа. В академической грамматике очень подробно описаны значения падежей (общие и частные). Правило Розенталя для видовой пары заслужить – заслуживать также можно объяснить, исходя из основных значений В.п. и Р.п. Заслужить (что) – глагол совершенного вида, обозначает  законченное  (ПОЛНОСТЬЮ выполненное) действие, поэтому это В.п. Заслуживать (чего) – глагол несовершенного вида, обозначает  незаконченное  (выполненное ЧАСТИЧНО) действие, поэтому это Р.п.

Comment: КАК Я ПОНИМАЮ СВЕТ И ПОКОЙ. Наша Вселенная основана на дуализме: Свет и Тьма, Добро и Зло, это ее основной закон. Именно противоположности обеспечивают ее нормальное развитие, поэтому  силы Света и Тьмы конструктивны, пока работают  по задуманному плану. Человек похож на батарейку –источник Света, когда он излучает Свет (высокую энергию), сталкиваясь с низкими энергиями, а это происходит постоянно. Нам приходится преодолевать вызовы материи (плотного мира), а также искушения тонкого мира Тьмы (низких вибраций). Так рождается светлая энергия, которую мы отдаем Творцу.

Comment: Но не всегда это получается, и человек начинает испытывать негативные эмоции, которые роднят его с миром Тьмы. В конце жизни подводится итог: душа уходит в мир Света или Тьмы или возвращается на повторное испытание/обучение. 
Покой – это неподвижное (статичное) состояние, отдых для души. Мастер получил от Света подарок (выигрыш в лотерею), чтобы создать великий роман. С этой задачей он справился, но «провалил» вторую часть экзамена, так как не смог донести его до людей. Поэтому он не заслужил Света, и уставшая душа получила временный отдых.

Answer (score 0):

Насчет "оффспина" про падеж "покоя"

Нашел у Греча формулировку о зависимости от вида глагола [тут](https://books.google.ru/books?id=xqwZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6&source=bl&ots=5U_CrjglOV&sig=fpP2w7K7Q48kXPyKrl6iI09cNh0&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQhPDZ0LDeAhUhtYsKHZzEBn44ChDoATAEegQIBBAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0&f=false).
То есть, откуда растут ноги у этого "правила", уже ясно.

Но, судя по всему, от Греча до Мережковского императивность правила ушла. Так что Розенталь (если понимать его по grizzly) расходится с общей практикой. Поэтому вопрос пока не закрыт.

Ну и на основной вопрос жду ответа.