# "Мастер и Маргарита": противопоставление света и покоя.

Tags: семантика, литературоведение

В продолжение булгаковской темы.
[Критика и рецензии на "Мастер и Маргарита"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445002)

*Я разделил вопрос ["Мастер и Маргарита" - он заслужил покой/покоя](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445004) на два.
Падежи падежами, но изначально-то основной вопрос был о семантике, вернее - о смысле этой фразы у Булгакова.*

***Одна из самых загадочных фраз романа: "Он не заслужил света, он заслужил покой".

Как её понимать? Что такое "свет" и "покой"?***

Не буду скрывать, знаю с десяток толкований разной степени правдоподобия. Но, возможно, есть что-то заслуживающее внимания. Так что все обоснованные версии принимаются.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы знаете столько версий, то каких чудес ждёте от форума русского языка? Есть же форумы по Булгакову. Ну, по делу.

1) Речь о форме загробной жизни. Чтобы "Взять Мастера с собой" по приказу Иешуа, Воланду нужно убить его и Маргариту.

2) Свет -- аналог рая, куда попадают праведники (Иешуа и Левий Матвей) и те, кто искупил грех (Пилат). В свет ведёт лунная дорога.

3) Никакого противопоставления света и покоя нет. Покой, скорее, ближе к чистилищу. В нём нет идеи страдания. Противопоставить покою надо участь Пилата, потому что он совершил самый худший грех -- трусость. Пилат не в покое, а в страдании. Но не по-христиански, не вечно.

4) Те, кто заслужил свет, не отреклись от своих идей. Мастер не таков. Его грех, как минимум, уныние. Поэтому его и не берут в рай.

5) Корни этих идей надо поискать в рассказах Густава Майринка. Булгаков активно подворовывал его сюжеты, персонажей и мысли. "Ангел Западного Окна" и "Зелёный лик" -- главные источники для "Мастера и Маргариты". Ещё был рассказ, точь в точь первая глава романа Булгакова. Название забыл. В других романах у Майринка нет чего-то, взятого Булгаковым. Но вот рассказы стоит посмотреть. Наверняка, там найдёте и свет, и покой и искупление. Вообще у него стандартный финал -- объединение мужского и женского начал. Не напоминает воссоединение Мастера и Маргариты?

Comment: Чего жду? Ну вот хотя бы вот этого: *Корни этих идей надо поискать в рассказах Густава Майринка*.

Comment: *Покой, скорее, ближе к чистилищу* - . так єто и есть противопоставление. По сути: возможно в принципе, но как-то очень не по контексту. Чистилище - место временного пребывания. А по Булгакову выходит, что он ставит точки окончательные. "Вечный покой".

Comment: У Булгакова вообще свой вариант христианского сеттинга. И Иешуа не совсем Иисус,  и Левия Матвея в Евангелии нет. Чистилище у него тоже явно не типичное. Поэтому я и говорю: "скорее, ближе к чистилищу", в том смысле, что оно между раем и адом. Как видно, у Булгакова временно пребывает именно Пилат, худший из грешников. Это при том, что по логике это ад. И всё же Пилат там именно очищается в муках.

Answer (score 0):

свет - это рай
тут вы правы,
но это философский рай, 
и Булгаков ничего не "подворовывал" у немецкого философа,
он активно изучал библиотеки и в Германии и в России (это давно известно, это был титанический труд),
эти мысли и тогда, и сейчас находятся  в активном обсуждении, впрочем, совершенно бессмысленном с точки зрения, человеческой (современной) философии, ибо мы пока не понимаем (или не никогда не сможем понять), что это. Но думать об этом, можно, наверное.